# Consultas preparadas con PDO

Tags: php

Me gustaría realizar una petición simple a mi base de datos local usando PDO. Realmente no entiendo cuando pruebo mi código, aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

( ! )

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$registro' (**T_VARIABLE**), expecting '**,**' or '**;**' in C:\wamp64\www\Pildorasinformaticas\28.1. Consultas preparadas con PDO.php on line **28**

Tal vez sea un simple error de sintaxis, pero no logro localizarlo.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
<?php
try {

  $base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=pruebas', 'root', '');
  $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $base=exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
  $sql = "SELECT NOMBREARTÍCULO, SECCIÓN, PRECIO, PAÍSDEORÍGEN
  FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE NOMBREARTÍCULO = ?";

  $resultado = $base->prepare($sql);
  $resultado->execute(array("Destornillador"));

  while ($registro = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "Nombre Artículo: " . $registro['NOMBREARTÍCULO'] .
    "Sección: " . $registro['SECCIÓN'] .
    "Precio: " $registro['PRECIO'] .
    "País de origen" . $registro['PAÍSDEORIGEN'] . "<br>";
  }

  $resultado->closeCursor();

} catch(Exception $e) {
  die('Error: ' . $e->GetMessage());
}
?>
```

Comment: dice linea 28 que hay un `$registro` y debería haber una `,` o un `;`

Comment: tabulando el código se ve que falta un `.` ó `,` entre el string `"Precio"`  y `$registro` en `"Precio: " $registro['PRECIO'] .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para evitar errores como ese, conviene escribir el código más organizado, de forma que te permita revisar la uniformidad en una sola vista, por ejemplo:

```
  $strHTML="";
  while ($registro = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $strHTML.="Nombre Artículo: " . $registro['NOMBREARTÍCULO'] .
              "Sección: "         . $registro['SECCIÓN'] .
              "Precio: "          . $registro['PRECIO'] .
              "País de origen: "  . $registro['PAÍSDEORIGEN'] . "<br>";
  }
  echo $strHTML;
```

Así puedes darte cuenta si falta algún `.` de concatenación, si en alguno de los valores te faltan los `:`, como era el caso de `País de origen`, etc.

Ya como recomendación, evita el uso de acentos o `ñ` en nombres de variables o de tablas o columnas de la base de datos, puede ser problemático en escenarios donde descuides manejar bien la codificación.

---

### EDICIÓN CON RESPECTO AL NUEVO ERROR

El nuevo error surgido:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on string

es debido a que en esta línea:

```
$base=exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

en vez de aplicar el comando `exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8")` lo que haces es igualar la variable `$base` al resultado de ese comando. O sea, al hacer eso, ya `$base` no representa a tu objeto conexión, sino que es una simple cadena.

Esto se puede resolver simplemente así:

```
$base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

Pero es mucho mejor configurar de forma definitiva tu objeto PDO de una vez por todas, pasándole un array de opciones con las configuraciones necesarias e indicándole el charset dentro del dsn. De ese modo, no tienes que seguir invocando métodos para aplicar más configuraciones una vez creado el objeto.

Lo que haremos será crear un array que incluye tanto esto `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`  como otra configuración muy importante que es establecer las preparaciones emuladas a `FALSE`. PDO trae `TRUE` por defecto y con esta opción en `TRUE` algunos habilidosos pueden colarnos instrucciones SQL dañinas emulando consultas preparadas.

El código quedaría así:

```
<?php
try {

  $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas;charset=utf8";
  $arrOptions = array(
                        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
                        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                     );
  $base=new PDO($dsn, 'root', '',$arrOptions);
  $sql = "SELECT NOMBREARTÍCULO, SECCIÓN, PRECIO, PAÍSDEORÍGEN
  FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE NOMBREARTÍCULO = ?";

  $resultado = $base->prepare($sql);
  $resultado->execute(array("Destornillador"));

  $strHTML="";
  while ($registro = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $strHTML.="Nombre Artículo: " . $registro['NOMBREARTÍCULO'] .
              "Sección: "         . $registro['SECCIÓN'] .
              "Precio: "          . $registro['PRECIO'] .
              "País de origen: "  . $registro['PAÍSDEORIGEN'] . "<br>";
  }
  echo $strHTML;

  $resultado->closeCursor();

} catch(Exception $e) {
  die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Comment: Sabia que era un simple error de sintaxis... :') ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: El error de resultado que me aparece ahora es el siguiente (después de modificar el codigo que me recomiendas):

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in C:\wamp64\www\Pildorasinformaticas\28.1. Consultas preparadas con PDO.php on line 22

Comment: @MarioG.Lucas en efecto, aquí tienes un error: `$base=exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");`, porque lo que haces es igualar tu anterior objeto `PDO`  al resultado de  `exec`, el cual produce un string. Ahora edito la respuestas dándote una recomendaciones para manipular mejor la conexión.

Comment: Muchas gracias.. Te estoy muy agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está porque tiene una tilde en el index (PAÍSDEORIGEN)

Trata de quitarle esa tilde:
$registro['PAISDEORIGEN'];

Avisame si te ayudó

Comment: No es por eso. Se pueden poner tilden en registros de tablas para luego ser llamadas. Gracias igualmente :)